# Mouseover - How do i trigger it multiple times?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to do a horizontal image slider.

When I do a `mouseover` it will only do the `.scrollLeft` / trigger the function once and move the images 1px which is expected but how do I make it run as long as the mouse is on the `mouseover` event?

Sample site [here](http://www.xch07.wi2.sde.dk/sandbox/slideLeftRight/index.php)

Answers sample [here](http://www.xch07.wi2.sde.dk/sandbox/slideLeftRight1/index.php)

HTML

```
    <div class="flex">
        <div id="slideLeft" class="center-c slideLeft"><div class="left"></div></div>
        <div id="slideRight" clasS="center-c slideRight"><div class="right"></div></div>
        <div id="imagesWrapper" class="imagesWrapper flex">
            <img src="img/1.jpg">
            <img src="img/2.jpg">
            <img src="img/3.jpg">
            <img src="img/4.jpg">
            <img src="img/5.jpg">
            <img src="img/6.jpg">
            <img src="img/7.jpg">
            <img src="img/8.jpg">
            <img src="img/9.jpg">
            <img src="img/10.jpg">
            <img src="img/11.jpg">
            <img src="img/12.jpg">
            <img src="img/13.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
                //IMAGE SCROLL
                var slideLeft = document.getElementById('slideLeft');
                var slideRight = document.getElementById('slideRight');
                var imagesWrapper = document.getElementById('imagesWrapper');
    
                    slideLeft.addEventListener('mouseover', profileMouseOverLeft, false);
                    slideRight.addEventListener('mouseover', profileMouseOverRight, false);
    
    
                function profileMouseOverLeft() {
                    imagesWrapper.scrollLeft += -1;
//                profileMouseOverLeft();
                }
                function profileMouseOverRight() {
                    imagesWrapper.scrollLeft += 1;
//                profileMouseOverRight();
                }
```

If I call the functions inside it will just go straight to the end immediately.

And if I change the functions to this, they will just run forever...

```
            function profileMouseOverLeft() {
//                alert("Hi");
                imagesWrapper.scrollLeft += -1;
//                profileMouseOverLeft();
                setInterval(function(){
                    alert("Hello");
                    profileMouseOverLeft();
                }, 100);
            }
            function profileMouseOverRight() {
//                alert("Hello");
                imagesWrapper.scrollLeft += 1;
                setInterval(function(){
                    profileMouseOverRight();
                }, 100);
//                profileMouseOverRight();
            }
```

Edit the final JS looks like this and works pretty well

```
            //IMAGE SCROLL
            var slideLeft = document.getElementById('slideLeft');
            var slideRight = document.getElementById('slideRight');
            var imagesWrapper = document.getElementById('imagesWrapper');
            var profileRightInterval;
            var profileLeftInterval;
            
            slideLeft.addEventListener('mouseover', profileMouseOverLeft, false);
            slideRight.addEventListener('mouseover', profileMouseOverRight, false);


            function profileMouseOverLeft() {                
                profileLeftInterval = setInterval(function () {
                    profileMoveLeft();
                }, 25);
            }
            function profileMouseOverRight() {
//                alert("Musen er nu inde");
                profileRightInterval = setInterval(function () {
                    profileMoveRight();
                }, 25);
            }
            function profileMoveLeft(){
                imagesWrapper.scrollLeft += -10;
            }
            function profileMoveRight(){
                imagesWrapper.scrollLeft += 10;
            }
            slideLeft.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
                clearInterval(profileLeftInterval);
            });
            slideRight.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
                clearInterval(profileRightInterval);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need combination of mouseover and mouseout event.
On mouseover event, use setInterval as you did.

Then in, mouseout event, use [**clearInterval()**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) function to interrupt your SetInterval function.

Comment: It seems like it just stacks the 1px and roll all the way when i do a setInterval

Comment: I managed to do something very similair to what you suggested :)

Comment: Glad I could help:)

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to use is a combination of `mouseover`, `mouseout`, and `mousemove`.

In a nutshell, the process is:
- on `mouseover`, add the `mousemove` event and record the mouse's x and y
- on `mouseout`, remove the `mousemove` event
- on `mousemove`, compare the x and y to the previous step. If it's moved so much, do something.

In your case, it looks like you want to move it every 1px, so you would do something every step.

It'd be something like this:

```
let lastX, lastY;
function mouseMoveFunc(e) {
  const diffX = e.clientX - lastX;
  const diffY = e.clientY - lastY;
  lastX = e.clientX;
  lastY = e.clientY;

  // do something with diffX and diffY
}

slideLeft.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) { 
  slideLeft.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveFunc);
  lastX = e.clientX;
  lastY = e.clientY;
}

slideLeft.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
  slideLeft.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveFunc);
}
```

Now, every time you move the mouse, the `mousemove` function will trigger and you'll be able to do something with the difference (how much the mouse moved between each tick).

It's important to add and remove the `mousemove` event because it is a relatively expensive event that can trigger a lot, and you don't want it happening if it doesn't need to.

Comment: I updated question with a sample website,  nothing seems to happen.. i cant use the js function .scrollLeft?

Comment: Im not sure how the clientX/Y will help me achieve the effect?